# MATLAB: interpolation inside ODE solver loop

Tags: matlab, interpolation, ode

What's the most efficient way to perform interpolation inside ODE solver loop? Now I have to create griddiedInterpolant objects and pass them through global variable. Performing three interpolations per call takes **40%** of computational time.

Data preparation:

```
options.Fx = griddedInterpolant(Mach, AD_data.Fx,'pchip');

options.Fy_alpha = griddedInterpolant(Mach, AD_data.Fy_alpha,'pchip');
options.Mz_alpha = griddedInterpolant(Mach, AD_data.Mz_alpha,'pchip');
```

Main code:

```
global options;

Fx = options.Fx(M);
Fy = options.Fy_alpha(M) * alpha;

Mz = options.Mz_alpha(M) * alpha;
```

So, is there any way to vectorize interpolations calls?